# red5pro SSL with AWS EC2

Tags: ssl, amazon-ec2, red5, red5pro

I have successfully installed the red5pro server at my AWS EC2 instance. Works with [http](http://stream.gettoworkout-live.de/). To allow the access to my webcam I need to install an SSL certificate. I have set all inbound ports required for red5pro to work with SSL at my EC2 instance.

I have followed [this](https://www.red5pro.com/docs/server/red5prossl.html) guide from red5pro docs to get my certificate with letsencrypt. I have all the files mentioned there:

```
sudo ls /etc/letsencrypt/live/stream.gettoworkout-live.de/
cert.pem   fullchain_and_key.p12  keystore.jks  tomcat.cer
chain.pem  fullchain.pem          privkey.pem   truststore.jks
```

After configuring red5pro to work with SSL (making said changes in red5.properties etc) I have tested my configuration with the mentioned open SSL test:

```
openssl s_client -connect stream.gettoworkout-live.de:443
```

The console output is:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
```

After setting the debug option:

```
CONNECTED(00000003)    
write to 0xed22d0 [0xed2350] (305 bytes => 305 (0x131))
    0000 - 16 03 01 01 2c 01 00 01-28 03 03 c9 07 ca 58 2d   ....,...(.....X-
    0010 - 6f 9f b2 24 d6 6c af 3a-ad 2f 44 c1 54 18 9e 14   o..$.l.:./D.T...
    0020 - b8 57 5a 53 b0 23 eb 0b-fd 03 1d 00 00 aa c0 30   .WZS.#.........0
    0030 - c0 2c c0 28 c0 24 c0 14-c0 0a 00 a5 00 a3 00 a1   .,.(.$..........
    0040 - 00 9f 00 6b 00 6a 00 69-00 68 00 39 00 38 00 37   ...k.j.i.h.9.8.7
    0050 - 00 36 00 88 00 87 00 86-00 85 c0 32 c0 2e c0 2a   .6.........2...*
    0060 - c0 26 c0 0f c0 05 00 9d-00 3d 00 35 00 84 c0 2f   .&.......=.5.../
    0070 - c0 2b c0 27 c0 23 c0 13-c0 09 00 a4 00 a2 00 a0   .+.'.#..........
    0080 - 00 9e 00 67 00 40 00 3f-00 3e 00 33 00 32 00 31   ...g.@.?.>.3.2.1
    0090 - 00 30 00 9a 00 99 00 98-00 97 00 45 00 44 00 43   .0.........E.D.C
    00a0 - 00 42 c0 31 c0 2d c0 29-c0 25 c0 0e c0 04 00 9c   .B.1.-.).%......
    00b0 - 00 3c 00 2f 00 96 00 41-c0 11 c0 07 c0 0c c0 02   .<./...A........
    00c0 - 00 05 00 04 c0 12 c0 08-00 16 00 13 00 10 00 0d   ................
    00d0 - c0 0d c0 03 00 0a 00 ff-01 00 00 55 00 0b 00 04   ...........U....
    00e0 - 03 00 01 02 00 0a 00 1c-00 1a 00 17 00 19 00 1c   ................
    00f0 - 00 1b 00 18 00 1a 00 16-00 0e 00 0d 00 0b 00 0c   ................
    0100 - 00 09 00 0a 00 23 00 00-00 0d 00 20 00 1e 06 01   .....#..... ....
    0110 - 06 02 06 03 05 01 05 02-05 03 04 01 04 02 04 03   ................
    0120 - 03 01 03 02 03 03 02 01-02 02 02 03 00 0f 00 01   ................
    0130 - 01
```

Nothing more. No success or error message. Could somebody help?

**UPDATE:**
This is the Output after -state -nbio:

```
SSL_connect:before/connect initialization
SSL_connect:SSLv2/v3 write client hello A
SSL_connect:error in SSLv2/v3 read server hello A
```

EDIT 2:
I have found out that my red5.log says

`"o.r.n.w.SecureWebSocketConfiguration - Keystore or Truststore file does not exist"`

I have installed red5pro in

```
/usr/local/red5pro
```

My keystore + truststore files are in

`/etc/letsencrypt/live/stream.gettoworkout-live.de/`

I reference the files in red5.properties with:

```
/etc/letsencrypt/live/stream.gettoworkout-live.de/truststore.jks
/etc/letsencrypt/live/stream.gettoworkout-live.de/keystore.jks
```

Comment: Your set-up as described seems correct, but the server not finding the jks files indicates it may be permission issue with the directory or files. Did you start your server with `sudo`?

Comment: I have set the .jks files to 600 and restarted the server. Works now. Thanks!